# CSS - Creating rounded rectangle

Tags: html, css, graphics, css-shapes

Is there a way to create a rounded button as shown in the picture using CSS (without using Canvas or SVG)?

[image: rounded rectangle]

edit: i'm not talking about border-radius, see the image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible using `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FF5656;
  border-radius: 1000px / 200px;
}
div:after, div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 72%;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: -6px;
  top: 14%;
  background: #FF5656;
}
div:after {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

#### Applying these borders to an `input` element:

Since, you can't apply :pseudo-elements to `input` elements, you'll have to apply the `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements to its container.

```css
input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FF5656;
  border-radius: 1000px / 200px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.btn-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.btn-container:after,
.btn-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 72%;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: -6px;
  top: 14%;
  background: #FF5656;
}
.btn-container:after {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <input type="button" value="Button" />
</div>
```

---

As @[misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) mentioned in comments, you could also use a `button` element to avoid using a container.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FF5656;
  border-radius: 1000px / 200px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button:after,
button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 72%;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: -6px;
  top: 14%;
  background: #FF5656;
}
button:after {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 1000px;
  left: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: got there before me, I see :P

Comment: [Might as well use `<button>` instead of `<input>`](http://jsbin.com/dawero/1/edit?html,css,output)... no need for the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type='button' class='rectangle' />
```

css

```
.rectangle{
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid red;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```